# MongoLab Remote API string to int conversion

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I'd like to be able to convert from a string to int a specific field. The only way I have so far is for my PHP script to update all existing values with an API call for each document that has that field. Is there a way for 1) MongoLab update values to utilize the existing value in an update call (ie in SQL you can do `price = price + 1`) and 2) can you call functions in MongoDB/MongoLab update calls? ie `{"price":"integer(price)"}`?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a program that goes through all your data and manually does the conversion. A simple Javascript program run in the mongo shell is probably the simplest way to go.